# Simple AWS CDK VPC Resource Deploy Failing Due to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to just deploy a simple VPC with AWS CDK.

However when I run this with `cdk deploy` I get the following errors:

> The stack named SharedVPCStack failed creation, it may need to be
> manually deleted from the AWS console: ROLLBACK_COMPLETE: Resource
> handler returned message: "Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check
> your file, then try to upload again.
>
> The following resource(s) failed to create:
> [FastVpcPublicSubnet2DefaultRouteC2BAE598,
> CustomVpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProviderHandlerDC833E5E,
> FastVpcPublicSubnet1DefaultRouteEF5405FB]. Rollback requested by user.

It seems to be trying to deploy a lambda function called `CustomVpcRestrictDefaultSGCustomResourceProviderHandlerDC833E5E` and failing to do that because it can't unzip some file.

Here is my stack code that I want to deploy.

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Stack,
    aws_ec2 as ec2
)

class SharedVpcStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, stage, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)

        self.vpc = ec2.Vpc(self, "FastVpc",
            vpc_name="my-vpc"
        )
```

I don't know how to resolve this error. I am not trying to deploy a lambda function but it seems to come with the VPC resource in CDK (so it's not a file I wrote that it can't unzip). Does anyone know how I can resolve this error or why I am seeing it? I am using `aws-cdk-lib` version 2.80.0

Comment: Related feature of CDK: [restrict access to default security group](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/25297).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue by deleting `cdk.out` in my local and then redeploying.